# ssh to amazon aws instance from virtual machine ubuntu 19.10

Tags: server, bash, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have aws instance key .pem file I saved that in a folder

```
"home/debian/cs605\ data\ management/assignment6/mumbai\ instance\ keys"
```

the key name is mumbai-instance-1.pem

I wrote a small bash script like this

```
!/bin/bash

AWS_KEY="home/debian/cs605\ data\ management/assignment6/mumbai\ instance\ keys"

ssh -v -i $AWS_KEY/mumbai-instance-1.pem
ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

the above file was saved named mumbai in following folder

> /home/debian/cs605 data management/assignment6

now I try to launch the script after `chmox +x mumbai`
but I am getting error

```
Warning: Identity file home/debian/cs605\ not accessible: No such file or directory.
OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6build1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname data\\: Name or service not known
./mumbai: line 6: ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com: command not found
```

so what is this error and how can I get rid of this.

**update 1**
I tried the method mentioned in answer

```
debian@osboxes:~/cs605 data management/assignment6$ ./mumbai
Warning: Identity file home/debian/cs605 data management/assignment6/mumbai instance keys/mumbai-instance-1.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]
./mumbai: line 6: ec2-user@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com: command not found
```

I checked the permissions of file

```
debian@osboxes:~/cs605 data management/assignment6/mumbai instance keys$ ls -l
total 8
-rwxr-xr-x 1 debian debian 1692 Mar  3 14:24 mumbai-instance-1.pem
-rwxrw-rw- 1 debian debian 1464 Mar  3 14:30 mumbai-instance-pvt.ppk
```

so I don't think this should be a permissions issue.

I did a mistake above in AWS_KEY it should be /home

**update2**

Now while fixing the above issues I get following when I execute the above script with AWS_KEY="/home/debian/cs605\ data\ management/assignment6/mumbai\ instance\ keys"

```
debian@osboxes:~/cs605 data management/assignment6$ ./mumbai
OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6build1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com [xx-xxx-xx-xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/debian/cs605 data management/assignment6/mumbai instance keys/mumbai-instance-1.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /home/debian/cs605 data management/assignment6/mumbai instance keys/mumbai-instance-1.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0p1 Ubuntu-6build1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:q5biO+y+QovuhX7TUfVShKOh7nQ/TaVUPhs8YI8EJOs
The authenticity of host 'ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com (xx-xxx-xx-xxx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:q5biO+y+QovuhX7TUfVShKOh7nQ/TaVUPhs8YI8EJOs.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com,xx-xxx-xx-xxx' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: debian@osboxes RSA SHA256:iFf3gBtMBnZsrEYwqUEZBanwk9vj6/nf64NfpGerACU agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/debian/cs605 data management/assignment6/mumbai instance keys/mumbai-instance-1.pem  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1001)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1001)


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: debian@osboxes RSA SHA256:iFf3gBtMBnZsrEYwqUEZBanwk9vj6/nf64NfpGerACU agent
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/debian/cs605 data management/assignment6/mumbai instance keys/mumbai-instance-1.pem
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0755 for '/home/debian/cs605 data management/assignment6/mumbai instance keys/mumbai-instance-1.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/home/debian/cs605 data management/assignment6/mumbai instance keys/mumbai-instance-1.pem": bad permissions
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
ec2-user@ec2-.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

ok I fixed it the key file should have 700 permission and 750 or 755 is not acceptible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the white space in your path, in that case you have to use quotes.

Try this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

AWS_KEY="/home/debian/cs605 data management/assignment6/mumbai instance keys"

ssh -v -i "$AWS_KEY"/mumbai-instance-1.pem
ec2-user@ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Just remove extra slashes in variable `$AWS_KEY` and use `""` when you use it.

Comment: ok I did what you tried now I am getting a permissions error not sure why is that coming. I updated the error in question, ok I got the error I did not added / at the beginning. Just dont want to do addiotional comment so updated here

Comment: oh i think we both forget about slash before "/home/..."  instead "home/..." :))

Comment: yes I updated the question slightly with update2 now ok now every thing is working perfectly fine.